# Where to find NuGet API key?

Tags: visual-studio, api, nuget, key, visual-studio-2019

When I try to build a release version of my program in VS2019 it opens PowerShell and displays this message:

```
" (An API key must be provided in the 'X-NuGet-ApiKey' header to use this service)".
```

Where can I find this API key?

Comment: I think the operation which you did is to push a nuget package to the official NuGet clients.And the apikey is on your account of [nuget.org website](https://www.nuget.org). Log on the website and click your account-->click on the `Api Keys`. So you can create the api keys for your own account. And when you create the api keys and click `Copy` to save the keys on the text. After that, you can use it to push or delete nuget packages.

Comment: @Raghavendra: regarding your edit on this question, please do not add please-help begging on behalf of other people. We prefer succinct questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where can I find this API key?

I think your operation is about pushing (or delete) a nuget package into the official nuget.org client which use this API key do some operation in your name. The API key is required when you publish or remove the nuget package from the nuget org client in the form of command line.

In fact, the API key is on your account of the [nuget.org website](https://www.nuget.org/).

**Solution**

**1)** open [nuget.org website](https://www.nuget.org/) and log in to your account.

**2)** click on your account, choose **API Keys** and then click **create** to create a new api leys.

**3)** After doing some configuration, when you finish it, please do not forget to click **Copy** to save the API keys for using later.

It's like a mixed string of alphanumeric characters like this:

```
xx2ogj5adrvmnuzmq2gqj2kkipgpecyezgjv5dvnaxxxxx
```

It belongs to yourself to use.

After that, when you enter your program, please use this API key and I think the error will not happen again.

[image]

**In addition**, you can check [this document](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/4259-cant-publish-to-nugetorg) to see whether it does help.